# jQuery Dialog still open when clicking the back button

Tags: jquery, dialog

I currently use the dialog to display a "loading" dialog when user clicks certain actions on my site. However, if the user clicks a link and the page starts loading, and after the user clicks the back button, the loading modal is still showing. How do I get it to not show? Here are the settings:

```
jQuery("#loader").dialog({
    autoOpen    : false,
    modal       : true,
    draggable   : false,
    position    : "center",
    resizable   : false,
    height      : 50,
    width       : 50,
    hide        : "slide"
});
```

This only happens on some pages. Typically ones that take a lot of time to load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your jquery script inside of a `document.ready` block

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#loader").dialog({
        autoOpen    : false,
        modal       : true,
        draggable   : false,
        position    : "center",
        resizable   : false,
        height      : 50,
        width       : 50,
        hide        : "slide"
    });
});
```

this will prevent your jquery script from running before the document is load and ready